# Why does this JQuery code break on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, mobile

I have the following code that works in all desktop browsers:

JQuery:

```
$('.select-one-style').on('click',function(){
    $('.select-one-style').removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var radioBtn = $(this).children('input[type=radio]');
    radioBtn.prop('checked', true);
})
```

HTML:

```
            <div class="choice-box select-one-style">
                <img src="/static/shipment/images/style-wall-street.jpg" alt="Wall Street" />
                <p>Wall Street</p>
                <input type="radio" name="look-type" value="wall-street" />
            </div>
            <div class="choice-box select-one-style">
                <img src="/static/shipment/images/style-classic.jpg" alt="Classic" />
                <p>Classic</p>
                <input type="radio" name="look-type" value="classic" />
            </div>
            <div class="choice-box select-one-style">
                <img src="/static/shipment/images/style-hipster.jpg" alt="Hipster" />
                <p>Hipster</p>
                <input type="radio" name="look-type" value="hipster" />
            </div>
            <div class="choice-box select-one-style">
                <img src="/static/shipment/images/style-preppy.jpg" alt="Preppy" />
                <p>Preppy</p>
                <input type="radio" name="look-type" value="preppy" />
            </div>
```

However, every time I visit my site using a mobile browser (both Safari & Chrome) on iOS (have not tested android yet), the radio button is not checked when I tap the images/inputs (although CSS effects will take place so I know the touch event is being registered as a click).

Anyone know why this code breaks on mobile?  Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried: `.on("click touchstart", function()...`

Comment: Sorry, ignore above, just re-read the question and saw that the click is being registered.

Comment: Try passing an event into your anonymous function and checking what event.currentTarget equals. If it's the image itself then $(this).children('input[type=radio]') will be [], whereas $(this).siblings().filter('input[type=radio]') will work.

Comment: You do realize you're re-implementing something that comes OOB when you make use of semantic tagging ? `<label for="xxx">` tag does exactly what you apparently want to achieve, i.e. : checking a radiobutton (or checkbox) by clicking the label...

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening due to 300 ms delay(tapping delay) in ios 8.
You can try introducing this meta tag to avoid that delay (read from various sources)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

I hope it will work for at least mobile-chrome browser on ios. Just give it a try